# Grouping Values and Summing & New Data Frame - Using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I've been looking for an answer this for awhile today, and every variation I'm trying, it's not working.

Problem statement - Add up the totals of "month" column below, so it shows one time, and create a new data-frame:

I've been a variety of groupby options, but I end up creating errors.

Exists now:

```
   ╔═══════╦════════════╦═════════╗
   ║ Month ║ Withdrawal ║ Deposit ║
   ╠═══════╬════════════╬═════════╣
   ║    10 ║         50 ║      40 ║
   ║    10 ║         50 ║      60 ║
   ║     6 ║         25 ║      10 ║
   ║     6 ║         30 ║      10 ║
   ║     3 ║        125 ║      60 ║
   ║     2 ║        100 ║      10 ║
   ╚═══════╩════════════╩═════════╝
```

Desired Output:

```
   ╔═══════╦════════════╦═════════╗
   ║ Month ║ Withdrawal ║ Deposit ║
   ╠═══════╬════════════╬═════════╣
   ║    10 ║        100 ║     100 ║
   ║     6 ║         55 ║      20 ║
   ║     3 ║        125 ║      60 ║
   ║     2 ║        100 ║      10 ║
   ╚═══════╩════════════╩═════════╝
```

EDIT:

Here's my code - it's pulling from another dataFrame:

```
mf = pd.DataFrame()
mf['Month'] = df['Month']
mf['Withdrawals'] = df['Withdrawals']
mf['Deposits'] = df['Deposits']
mf['Month'] = mf.groupby('Month', as_index=False).sum()
print(mf)
```

When I do that, it outputs this:

```
    ╔═══════╦═════════════╦══════════╗
    ║ Month ║ Withdrawals ║ Deposits ║
    ╠═══════╬═════════════╬══════════╣
    ║     1 ║ 206.94      ║ 300      ║
    ║     2 ║ 256.5       ║ 10.12    ║
    ║     3 ║ 40          ║ 52.31    ║
    ║     4 ║ 150         ║ 15.99    ║
    ║     5 ║ 1486.86     ║ 15.99    ║
    ║   755 ║ NaN         ║ NaN      ║
    ║   756 ║ NaN         ║ NaN      ║
    ║   757 ║ NaN         ║ NaN      ║
    ║   758 ║ NaN         ║ NaN      ║
    ║   759 ║ NaN         ║ NaN      ║
    ╚═══════╩═════════════╩══════════╝
```

So looking at the output, it didn't put them all in month 1-12...

Comment: `df.groupby('Month', as_index=False).sum()`?

Comment: didn't work, but added formulas above to be more clear.

Comment: No, do not assign anything, just `mf = df.groupby('Month', as_index=False).sum()`.

Comment: Got it, and it solved the problem. Assigning it is what was screwing it up.